# Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have been trying to use android studio emulator but I can not run my App on the Emulator. When I Run my App it shows the emulator with following details:

- Hax is enabled
- Hax ram_size 0x40000000
- HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
- Console on port 5554; ADB on port 5555

After that it takes to next TAB Launching app and shows waiting for the device to come online. After that it shows error:

```
Error while waiting for device: Time out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

Anyone know any solution.

Comment: make sure  you have `install` latest version tool ?

Answer (score 7):

Although there could be various reasons for this behaviour....
**Mostly** it may be due to error in **system images** or the **API version** you are using

better you download **latest system images** and make sure the compatibilty of API version you are using.

[image]

If problem exists

I would like to suggest some fixes:
Try them

1)Uninstall/Reinstall Android SDK to folder.

OR

2) delete the emulator and create another emulator targeted at the appropriate API Level.

OR

3)create a new Virtual Device.

OR

4)set "Max VM application heap size" hardware property to 192 or higher and pick the QVGA skin.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ Amylinn for your answer. I can do the above work but show the same Error message. What can i do to solve this Error??????

Comment: with 5000 views, with thanks... and 0 upvote... ? thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing this timeout error. Here is the solution worked for me

Launch Task Manager -> Search for adb.exe in process list->End the process->Try relaunching the emulator it will start.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcOIrtimMU

Click on app: edit configurations;

In Launch Options: choose Specific Activity

In Activity: specify your main class: com.example.budgetapp.MainActivity

And, run.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me:

GoTo SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Check that the android emulator has the latest version and If doesn't install the updates.

I had the same error described here.

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Check updates.... Emulator had an update.
After I updated worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of posts. But none of them seemed to work for me. Every time I tried to start the emulator, the process seemed to be "not responding" after a minute or so. I tried restarting my PC, adb, created new devices, even re-installed Android Emulator, but nothing worked.
Surprisingly enough, what worked though was to move the emulator out of Android Studio.

- Go to `Preferences` -> search for `Emulator` -> Uncheck `Launch in a tool window`

I am using Mac M1 Pro with Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the AVD Manager.
2. Create a new AVD or edit an existing AVD.
3. In the Verify Configuration page, specify the Emulated Performance: Graphics change to sofware or hadware

good luck

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything here and other questions too, but the only solution for me was to create a new AVD.
Also downgraded from Pixel3XL to Pixel2, not sure if it matters. (Kept same android version)