# Runtime Error: Android Studio cannot load Emulator and waiting for 300 seconds

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When i am running my program through android studio, but it cannot load the device to launch the android emulator. i have tried to enabling and disabling of AVD and also run some command on android terminal. It just processed the running and failed after 300 seconds.

[image]

Comment: This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367085/error-while-waiting-for-device-timed-out-after-300seconds-waiting-for-emulator

Answer (score 0):

try this 
change Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.

Comment: It doesn't work as my adb is settle.

Comment: whats is your computer RAM size

Comment: @shivamgoyal check my update ans

Comment: RAM size 8GB(i5)