# Android emulator "Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online" error

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

First of all, I know that the title is similar to the other questions that asked here, but my problem is a bit different, and I couldn't find a solution.

The thing is, I've created an emulator and used it with no problem, but after I entered a Gmail account to the emulator, set the PIN for lockscreen and turned the emulator off after using it for a while, I can't turn it on back. It is stuck on black screen and after some time, it gives

```
"Timed out after 300 seconds waiting for emulator to come online"
```

error.

I know that wiping data solves the problem, but I don't want to wipe data because I don't want to enter an account and do the same process again and again. My other emulators are working fine because they have no Gmail account.

(Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1 running on Windows 11 22H2)

Things that I have tried:

1- Wipe data (it works but I don't want to do the entire process again, I need that account)

2- Change Graphics settings from Automatic to Software (didn't work)

3- Delete *.lock files in avd folder (didn't work)

4- Update emulator (I'm using the latest version and I believe maybe it's because of the update)

5- Update Android Studio (using the latest version)

6- Use the power button (not working)

7- Invalidate cached (not working)

Comment: try  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40726203/6834114

Comment: I did but nothing happened.

Comment: @harundemir918 have you found any solution for that.

Comment: No I couldn't find any solution, I just wiped data.

Comment: I have this issue only on ubuntu and using emulator API 31 and above. on windows and macOS works without any problem.
after using a VPN this problem was solved in ubuntu too. it seems the emulator needs a connection on startup.
I am in Iran and can not use android studio normally due to US sanctions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try it if I encounter the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

this what solved my problem.
try the following steps:

Make sure that you have administrator privileges on your computer.   Navigate to the directory "C:\Users\username.android" Right-click on    the this file folder, and choose "Properties." In the Properties    window, go to the "Security" tab. Check if your user account has the    necessary permissions to access the file. If not, click "Edit" and    give yourself full control. Try restarting ADB and see if the issue    is resolved.

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try it if I encounter the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and after having tried basically all the solutions found out there, this was what worked for me:

Go to Preferences -> search for Emulator -> Uncheck Launch in a tool window

This is valid for virtual device.